# What would be the pros and cons of using .xyz domain?

Tags: web, urls

Recently I've seen a lot of people/companies migrating to the `.xyz` domain, including `Alphabet` with the [abc.xyz](http://abc.xyz/) domain.

What would be the benefits of using it, since it's being more and more popular? I've been using it in conjunction with `.com` domain - which redirects users to the main (`.xyz`) domain.

But clients and users keeping asking: "Why do you use `.xyz`?", "Is it safe?", "I never saw one before. Should I use it?"

So, what is the pros and cons of using it in an UX point of view?

What should I consider when chosing `.xyz` or `.com` (or any other domain - local or not, such as `.net`, `.inf`, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

You pointed out the cons:

- users are not familiar with it, therefore they don't trust it.
- they may have difficulties remembering the string "xyz". For example, they may type `yoursite.zyx`. On the other hand `.com` is much more easier to remember due to its popularity.

Positives:

- you can get one word domains like `hosting.xyz` for cheap, as opposed to `.com .net .org` where the one word domains can become expremely expensive.

Comment: Yes, they are not familiar with it. Yet. But big companies are migrating, it's a growing domain, so, why is this happening? There must be good reasons to use it.

Comment: In UX standpoint there are no reasons to use domains other than .com, .org, .net as they do not break the consistency. Companies use it because they can buy 1 word domains, like hosting.xyz, where in .com these domains are long long taken by someone.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov, but a one word domain is an obvious UX reason, contradicting your answer.  `hosting.xyz` is more user-friendly than `my_really_good_hosting_with_a_unique_name.com`.